# Build pipeline for xaml files

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, cd

I am trying to have a CI/CD pipeline for my project for which the output of the development is multiple xaml files.

I am trying to build a pipeline in Azure Devops tool. For build pipelines we have to select a task (for eg: for powershell scripts there is a powershell task) . Since our project files are xamls , what could we select here and complete our build pipeline?
Basically what are the build activities(like sonarQube and HPFortify for java project) that we can do on xaml files ? If there is none, can I bypass and have an empty build so that we can enter the release pipeline without much build checks. 
We dont need to package it into a separate package. It can remain as xaml files after the build and the CD pipelines can deploy it to a folder in the server.

Answer (score 1):

If your build artifact is just a bunch of XAML files then simply use a copy task to copy these to $(Build. ArtifactStagingDirectory)  and then use a publish drop task to take the contents of $(Build. ArtifactStagingDirectory) and store it on the server and you're done.

You don't have to have a build task you just need the files required for your release which the above couple of steps will do nicely.

Comment: Thanks Colin. Let me try this out

Comment: Hi @ColinB 
I tried this. But there was one problem due to the security settings in my organization. If I plan to publish this into my build server or onto an azure VM, the security settings will block it. Since the build agent have a dynamic ip address(I think) it is difficult for the security team to open a port for a paricular ip. Is there a solution that you can suggest for this.Thanks@Colin

Comment: The agent requires internet access (over SSL). The agent initiates this connection on an outgoing request and Azure DevOps just responds to this. If your organisation is shutting down internet access from the agent over SSL then I'm sorry this will never work for you.